# HIghchart show current month data with week interval

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I am using the highchart line graph to show the current month data in weekly interval.
But the chart lines not displayed
Here is my code:

```
    $(function () {
    $('#container').highcharts({
        chart: {
            type: 'line'
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Monthly Average Rainfall'
        },
        subtitle: {
            text: 'Source: WorldClimate.com'
        },
        xAxis: {
            type: 'datetime',
             min : Date.UTC(2015, 8, 1),
             max: Date.UTC(2015, 8, 30),
            dateTimeLabelFormats: {
                second: '%H:%M:%S',
                minute: '%H:%M',
                hour: '%H:%M',
                day: '%e. %b',
                week: '%e. %b',
                month: '%b \'%y',
                year: '%Y'
            },
            tickInterval: 7 * 24 * 3600 * 1000 // interval of 1 day
        },
         yAxis: [{ // left y axis
        title: {
            text: null
        },
        labels: {
            align: 'left',
            x: 3,
            y: 16,
            format: '{value:.,0f}'
        },
        showFirstLabel: false
    }, { // right y axis
        linkedTo: 0,
        gridLineWidth: 0,
        opposite: true,
        title: {
            text: null
        },
        labels: {
            align: 'right',
            x: -3,
            y: 16,
            format: '{value:.,0f}'
        },
        showFirstLabel: false
    }],
        tooltip: {
            headerFormat: '<span style="font-size:10px">{point.key}</span><table>',
            pointFormat: '<tr><td style="color:{series.color};padding:0">{series.name}: </td>' +
                '<td style="padding:0"><b>{point.y:.1f} mm</b></td></tr>',
            footerFormat: '</table>',
            shared: true,
            useHTML: true
        },
       legend: {
        align: 'left',
        verticalAlign: 'top',
        borderWidth: 0
    }, 

        /* plotOptions: {
            column: {
                pointPadding: 0,
                borderWidth: 0,
                groupPadding: 0.1,
                //pointStart: Date.UTC(2015, 1, 12) // feb 12, 2015
            }
        }, */

         plotOptions: {
        series: {
            cursor: 'pointer',
            point: {
                events: {
                    click: function (e) {
                        hs.htmlExpand(null, {
                            pageOrigin: {
                                x: e.pageX || e.clientX,
                                y: e.pageY || e.clientY
                            },
                            headingText: this.series.name,
                            maincontentText: Highcharts.dateFormat('%A, %b %e, %Y', this.x) + ':<br/> ' +
                                this.y + ' sessions',
                            width: 200
                        });
                    }
                }
            },
            marker: {
                lineWidth: 1
            }
        }
    },

        series: [{
            name: 'Tokyo',
            data: [49.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4],
            pointStart: Date.UTC(2015, 1, 12),
            pointInterval: 7 * 24 * 3600 * 1000 // interval of 1 day

        },
        {
            name: 'New York',
            data: [83.6, 78.8, 98.5, 93.4, 106.0, 84.5, 105.0, 104.3, 91.2, 83.5, 106.6, 92.3],
            pointStart: Date.UTC(2015, 1, 12),
            pointInterval: 7 * 24 * 3600 * 1000 // interval of 1 day

        }, {
            name: 'London',
            data: [48.9, 38.8, 39.3, 41.4, 47.0, 48.3, 59.0, 59.6, 52.4, 65.2, 59.3, 51.2],
            pointStart: Date.UTC(2015, 1, 12),
            pointInterval: 7 * 24 * 3600 * 1000 // interval of 1 day
        }, {
            name: 'Berlin',
            data: [42.4, 33.2, 34.5, 39.7, 52.6, 75.5, 57.4, 60.4, 47.6, 39.1, 46.8, 51.1],
            pointStart: Date.UTC(2015, 1, 12),
            pointInterval: 7 * 24 * 3600 * 1000 // interval of 1 day
        } 
]
    });
});
```

Can any one please suggest any solution to show the points in line chart for current month with week interval. I need the week interval like this highchart example https://www.highcharts.com/demo/line-ajax.

Answer (score 1):

You have set the `tickInterval` of `xAxis` to 7 days starts from `Date.UTC(2015, 8, 1)` to `Date.UTC(2015, 8, 30)` but set the `pointStart` of the `series` starts from `Date.UTC(2015, 1, 12)`.

So simply change the `pointStart` to `Date.UTC(2015, 8, 1)`.

BTW, `7 * 24 * 3600 * 1000` is 7 days.

`(7 days * hours per day * seconds per hour * milliseconds per second)`

```js
$(function() {
  $('#container').highcharts({
    chart: {
      type: 'line'
    },
    title: {
      text: 'Monthly Average Rainfall'
    },
    subtitle: {
      text: 'Source: WorldClimate.com'
    },
    xAxis: {
      type: 'datetime',
      gridLineWidth: 1,
      min: Date.UTC(2015, 8, 1),
      max: Date.UTC(2015, 8, 30),
      dateTimeLabelFormats: {
        second: '%H:%M:%S',
        minute: '%H:%M',
        hour: '%H:%M',
        day: '%e. %b',
        week: '%e. %b',
        month: '%b \'%y',
        year: '%Y'
      },
      tickInterval: 7 * 24 * 3600 * 1000 // interval of 1 day
    },
    yAxis: [{ // left y axis
      title: {
        text: null
      },
      labels: {
        align: 'left',
        x: 3,
        y: 16,
        format: '{value:.,0f}'
      },
      showFirstLabel: false
    }, { // right y axis
      linkedTo: 0,
      gridLineWidth: 0,
      opposite: true,
      title: {
        text: null
      },
      labels: {
        align: 'right',
        x: -3,
        y: 16,
        format: '{value:.,0f}'
      },
      showFirstLabel: false
    }],
    tooltip: {
      headerFormat: '<span style="font-size:10px">{point.key}</span><table>',
      pointFormat: '<tr><td style="color:{series.color};padding:0">{series.name}: </td>' +
        '<td style="padding:0"><b>{point.y:.1f} mm</b></td></tr>',
      footerFormat: '</table>',
      shared: true,
      useHTML: true
    },
    legend: {
      align: 'left',
      verticalAlign: 'top',
      borderWidth: 0
    },

    /* plotOptions: {
        column: {
            pointPadding: 0,
            borderWidth: 0,
            groupPadding: 0.1,
            //pointStart: Date.UTC(2015, 1, 12) // feb 12, 2015
        }
    }, */

    plotOptions: {
      series: {
        cursor: 'pointer',
        point: {
          events: {
            click: function(e) {
              hs.htmlExpand(null, {
                pageOrigin: {
                  x: e.pageX || e.clientX,
                  y: e.pageY || e.clientY
                },
                headingText: this.series.name,
                maincontentText: Highcharts.dateFormat('%A, %b %e, %Y', this.x) + ':<br/> ' +
                  this.y + ' sessions',
                width: 200
              });
            }
          }
        },
        marker: {
          lineWidth: 1
        }
      }
    },

    series: [{
        name: 'Tokyo',
        data: [
          [Date.UTC(2015, 8, 1), 49.9],
          [Date.UTC(2015, 8, 3), 71.5], 
          [Date.UTC(2015, 8, 5), 106.4], 
          [Date.UTC(2015, 8, 7), 129.2], 
          [Date.UTC(2015, 8, 9), 144.0], 
          [Date.UTC(2015, 8, 12), 176.0], 
          [Date.UTC(2015, 8, 15), 135.6], 
          [Date.UTC(2015, 8, 18), 148.5], 
          [Date.UTC(2015, 8, 21), 216.4], 
          [Date.UTC(2015, 8, 24), 194.1], 
          [Date.UTC(2015, 8, 27), 95.6], 
          [Date.UTC(2015, 8, 30), 54.4]
        ],
        
      },
      {
        name: 'New York',
        data: [83.6, 78.8, 98.5, 93.4, 106.0, 84.5, 105.0, 104.3, 91.2, 83.5, 106.6, 92.3],
        pointStart: Date.UTC(2015, 8, 1),
        pointInterval: 7 * 24 * 3600 * 1000 // interval of 1 day

      }, {
        name: 'London',
        data: [48.9, 38.8, 39.3, 41.4, 47.0, 48.3, 59.0, 59.6, 52.4, 65.2, 59.3, 51.2],
        pointStart: Date.UTC(2015, 8, 1),
        pointInterval: 7 * 24 * 3600 * 1000 // interval of 1 day
      }, {
        name: 'Berlin',
        data: [42.4, 33.2, 34.5, 39.7, 52.6, 75.5, 57.4, 60.4, 47.6, 39.1, 46.8, 51.1],
        pointStart: Date.UTC(2015, 8, 1),
        pointInterval: 7 * 24 * 3600 * 1000 // interval of 1 day
      }
    ]
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>

<div id="container" style="min-width: 310px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
```

Comment: Ok i forgot to change that it is working now one more thing if i fetch data from the database then how i can pass the date with the value to the series to display the point at proper place?

Comment: I edited one of the series to display at a proper date.

Comment: ok thank you can we show it the grid line displays for week like in the example https://www.highcharts.com/demo/line-ajax ?

Comment: add `gridLineWidth: 1,` to `xAxis`.